# Hadoop mapfile multiple indexing

Tags: hadoop, io

Having the following dataset input format : TextA TextB

Is it possible to use a single hadoop MapFile to provide indexing (binary search support) on the first column (TextA) and also on the second one (TextB) ?

The idea would be to have the same data folder, but with different index files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, the data file MUST be sorted by key.

If you try to visualize how MapFile is implemented you will figure out that it cannot work:

- The large data file is sorted by key
- The index file contains N keys are is loading in memory
- When you do a `get`, the two neighboring keys in the index file are found. Then a binary search is done in the large data file (that's why it must be sorted by key)

How would you meet the sorting requirement with a single file ?